# How to put pivot table using Shell script

Tags: shell, csv, pivot-table

I have data in a CSV file as below...

```
Emailid  Storeid      

a@gmail.com 2000

b@gmail.com 2001

c@gmail.com 2000

d@gmail.com 2000

e@gmail.com 2001
```

I am expecting below output, basically finding out how many email ids are there for each store.

```
StoreID    Emailcount

2000           3

2001           2
```

So far i tried to solve my issue

```
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
awk -F, '{ A[$1]+=$2 } END { OFS=","; for (x in A) print x,A[x]; }' > /home/ec2-user/storewiseemials.csv
done < temp4.csv
```

With the above shell script i am not getting desired output, Can you guys please help me?

Comment: Please post the complete script (for instance, the `done` is missing), and explain what `f1` and `f2` are supposed to contain; you set these variables, but never used them. Further, your `awk` command reads from standard input, but you don't have a input redirection.

Comment: Updated full script

Comment: You say that the output is not what you want, but you don't show the actual output.

Comment: @user1934428, awk will slurp up the input redirection of the while-read loop. The loop will iterate exactly once: `f1` will contain the first line of the file (since there are no commas in the file), and then `awk` will consume the rest of the file.

Comment: @SG131712, it doesn't look like your CSV has commas, so remove the `IFS` and `-F,` parts.

Comment: @glennjackman i mentioned output in my question. Under the line "basically finding out how many email ids are there for each store". And to give more idea on data i gave it in table format actually i have data in csv file

Comment: @glennjackman : Now that we see the whole program, it is obvious. Before the OP updated his post, this part was not visible.

Comment: @SG131712 : So, why are you setting the input field separator to a comma, when there is no comma in the CSV file you posted? And why do you assgn to the two variables, if you never use them?

Comment: @SG131712, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and reflect on the wisdom of showing us problem X when you're really asking about Y. Programming is a craft where it's extremely important to focus on the details. The answer to "basically finding out how many..." is "well, count them". If you want good answers, ask a good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and starting from this (I have used a CSV, because I do not know if you use a tab or a white space as separator)

```
Emailid,Storeid
a@gmail.com,2000
b@gmail.com,2001
c@gmail.com,2000
d@gmail.com,2000
e@gmail.com,2001
```

and running

```
mlr --csv count-distinct -f Storeid -o Emailcount input >output
```

you will have

```
+---------+------------+
| Storeid | Emailcount |
+---------+------------+
| 2000    | 3          |
| 2001    | 2          |
+---------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

The below should work:

```
IFS=","
while read f1 f2
do
awk -F, '{ A[$2]=$1; A[$2]++; } END { OFS=","; for (x in A) print x,A[x]; }' > /home/ec2-user/storewiseemials.csv
done < temp4.csv
```